# Create one table for unknown number of fields

Tags: mysql, performance

I have one form like this :

Option 1 - Value 1 (numeric)

Option 2 - Value 2 (numeric)

......

Option 459 - Value 459 (numeric)

"Add new option"

As you can see, I don't know how many options will be. I know only that if one option is accessed via url, I need to make + 1 somewhere for each time is accessed.

How should my table look... ?

Comment: Your table may looks like how you list it in the question : columns can be pivoted to rows. I.e :  each option and counts is a row

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a "long, narrow" table:

```
CREATE TABLE OptionValue (
 id INT --this is a surrogate primary key. Optional, but I like to have them.
,optionGroup INT --since you have more then one set of options stored here
,optionNo INT,
,Value numeric
)
```

Or something like that.